# XSD Schema validation throws SAXParseException in java application using Xerces fails when there are external xsd's included in the Parent

Tags: java, xml, validation, xerces, xsd-1.1

In my java application , I am trying to validate XSD1.1  Schema using XercesJ 2.12.2

My master xsd has multiple xsd's included, like below:

**XSD 1.1**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    vc:minVersion="1.1" version="1.0.16">
       <xs:include schemaLocation="NIEM_1.xsd"/>
       <xs:include schemaLocation="NIEM_2.xsd"/>
       <xs:include schemaLocation="NIEM_2.xsd"/>
```

But the validation code fails to load external schemas, and throws exceptions like the one below, wherever parent xsd is referencing types defined in included xsd.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1456; columnNumber: 79;
> src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'EYECodeSimpleType' to a(n) 'type
> definition' component.

**Java**

```
 SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1");
 Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(loadExampleSchema("Example.xsd")));
 Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
 validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())));
```

For reference, I am using the following jars:

- cupv10k-runtime.jar
- icu4j-69_1.jar
- org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor_1.2.1.jar
- xercesImpl.jar
- xml-apis.jar

Please Help.

I am expecting the java application to load all the included xsds and validates types defined in them.

Comment: Do you ensure that the main schema is loaded in a way that the parser/validator knows its URI to resolve relative ones included/imported? Also what does "embedded" mean exactly?

Comment: We need to see what `loadExampleSchema("Example.xsd")` does or why it isn't simply `new StreamSource(new File("Example.xsd"))` or `new StreamSource(systemId/URIgoesHere)`.

Comment: It is just converting the file into InutStream and returning it.

Comment: protected static InputStream loadExampleSchema(String schemaFilename) {
   
     InputStream inStream = null;

     try {
       ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(schemaFilename);
       inStream = resource.getInputStream();
        return inStream;
     } catch(IOException e) {
       throw new IllegalStateException(" Failed to read  schema file " + schemaFilename, e);
    
     }
   }

Comment: I tried loading in the following way as well \n    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new Source[] {
          new StreamSource(loadIncidentReportSchema("Example.xsd")),
          new StreamSource(loadIncidentReportSchema("NIEM_1.xsd")),
          new StreamSource(loadIncidentReportSchema("NIEM_2.xsd")),
          new StreamSource(loadIncidentReportSchema("NIEM_3.xsd"))
     
       });

Comment: Are all schemas in a ClassPathResource?

Comment: A class like https://github.com/schxslt/schxslt-java/blob/master/src/main/java/name/dmaus/schxslt/Resolver.java might help.

Comment: yes all are schemas are in a ClassPathResource

Comment: You need to add include statements in the main schema to reference child schemas.  See : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp

Answer (score 0):

To resolve a schema document reference such as

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="NIEM_1.xsd"/>
```

the schema processor needs to know the base URI of the containing schema document. With JAXP interfaces the usual way it gets to know this is using the `SystemId` property of the `Source` object. If you supply a `Source` that is not associated with any base URI, for example a simple byte stream or a DOM source, the processor has no idea where to look for the schema location.

A more helpful schema processor would, however, give you better diagnostics.

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: An example of what?

Answer (score 0):

So finally I figured out the solution. Here is the code snippet that worked for me. Thamk you all for pointers

```
 InputStream inStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xsdFileName);
      String  realPath= getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(xsdFileName).getFile();
      StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(inStream);
      streamSource.setSystemId(realPath);
      Source source = streamSource;
      Schema schema = factory.newSchema(source);
   
      // Create a Validator from the Schema
      Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
  validator.validate(new StreamSource(neByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())));
```